# Summernote WYSIWYG editor doesn't work correctly in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, wysiwyg, summernote

I want to have a textarea with WYSIWYG editor, however it doesnt work correctly. Here is a picture how my editor looks now:
[image: WYSIWYG problem]

And my code related to this textarea is:

```
<textarea class='form-control' placeholder='content' id='technig' ></textarea>
```

and also

```
 <script src="{!!asset('/assets/summernote/summernote.css')!!}"></script>
 <script src="{!!asset('/assets/summernote/summernote.min.js')!!}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#technig').summernote({
                height:300,
            });
        });
</script>
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: it seems like your scripts are not getting loaded correctly.  see in  console if it is present in resources tab. For debugging you can put cdn path for summernote and recheck if summernote need any other dependency such as angular, jquery etc.

Comment: sorry, dont really get. files are in public directory not in resources, because asset() loads "/public/" with cdn it absolutely doesnt work

Comment: solved now :) thanks for help

Comment: Glad it is solved. What was the problem?

Comment: Please add your own answer, @Danielius.

Comment: I dont really know, i just added cdn adn it worked, but it works only when BOTH cdn and same files in folder used. i dont get why :/ but it works, so, it's okay :)

Comment: try removing cdn's add the file uri's and reload, 
show the error's you see on console, so someone could add an answer, don;t leave it unanswered